# how to count using for each in xsl

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt, foreach

please see below , sample xml

```
<OuttypList>
   <Outtyp>
         <A>
            <P>0</P>
            <T>NoShare</T>
         </A>
   </Outtyp>
    <Outtyp>
        <Outtypform>Bank</Outtypform>
        <A>
            <A>
                <P>1000</P>
                <T>Share</T>
            </A>
            <S>100</S>
        </A>
        <B>         
            <C>3015</C>
            <D>James</D>
        </B>
    </Outtyp>
    <Outtyp>
    <Outtypform>Bank</Outtypform>
         <A>
            <P>10</P>
            <T>Share</T>
         </A>
   </Outtyp></OuttypList>
```

and I am displaying details of Outtyp and also after displaying each Outtyp I am inserting a space so that data looks good.

```
<xsl:for-each select="OuttypList/Outtyp">
<xsl:if test="normalize-space(Outtypform)">
--displaying details--
</xsl:if>
<xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="position() != last()">
              <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                          <span><text>&#160;</text></span>
                    </td>
              </tr>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise></xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Problem : right now with this code , it creates extra space initially which I dont want, so I dont want extra space line if there is no Outtypform present in Outtyp..need to change "for each" such that it should count Outtyp only on basis if Outtypform is present under Outtyp. For example - above sample xml have 3 Outtyp node ... .but only two contains 
so only two node with details should be displayed and extra space after each Outtyp.

Comment: Can you show the expected output?

Comment: _"should count Outtyp only on basis if Outtypform is present under Outtyp"_ >> while this is possible with `xsl:number`, it is much easier, and preferable, to use a predicate. In fact, every time you find yourself writing an `xsl:if` with a node test, you should consider very strongly to place it in the selection predicate instead.

Answer (score 1):

Either place the `xsl:choose` block inside the `xsl:if` block, or - preferably - change your selection to:

```
<xsl:for-each select="OuttypList/Outtyp[normalize-space(Outtypform)]">
```

Then you won't need the `xsl:if` at all.

*Untested, because the code provided is incomplete.*